# search between cards and show "not found" text

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using javascript to search between cards. It's working good, but my "not found" text is bugging. Sometimes when there is still a card, it displays the "not found" text. I'm a little bit confused because sometime it works good.
Here's my search bar:

```
<input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Keresés..." id="myFilter" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Kérem adja meg a keresett vállalkozást vagy tulajdonosa nevét!" onkeyup="myFunction()">
```

Here I make the text unvisible:

```
 <script>
     document.getElementById("notfound").style.display = "none";
    </script>
```

this is my searching function:

```
<script>
  function myFunction() {
      var input, filter, cards, cardContainer, notfound, title, i;
      input = document.getElementById("myFilter");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      cardContainer = document.getElementById("myItems");
      cards = cardContainer.getElementsByClassName("card");
      notfound = document.getElementById("notfound");

      for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
          title = cards[i].querySelector(".card-body h4.card-category");
          if (title.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
              cards[i].style.display = "";
              notfound.style.display = "none";

          } else {
              cards[i].style.display = "none";
              notfound.style.display = "";

          }
      }
  }
      </script>
```

one of the cards:

```
 <div class="col-md-4" <?php if ($record['visibility'] == 0) echo " style='display: none';"; ?>>
              <div class="card card-profile">
                <div class="card-avatar">
                  <a href="#">
                  <img class="img" src="assets/img/faces/avatar.png" />
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="card-top">
                  <h4 class="card-category text-gray"><b><?php echo $record['job']; ?></b><br>
                    <span style="color: black;"><?php echo $record['name']; ?></span></h4>
                  </div>
                  <hr>
                  <h5 class="card-description">
                  <i class="material-icons">
                      mobile_friendly
                      </i>
                      <b>tel.:</b> <?php echo $record['phone']; ?>
                    </h5>

                  <h5 class="card-description"  <?php if(empty($record['phone2'])){echo " style='display: none';"; }?>>
                  <i class="material-icons">
                      mobile_friendly
                      </i>
                      <b>tel2.:</b> <?php echo $record['phone2']; ?>
                    </h5>
                    <h5 class="card-description" <?php if(empty($record['email'])){echo " style='display: none';"; }?>>
                      <i class="material-icons">
                        email
                        </i>
                        <b> E-mail:</b> <?php echo $record['email']; ?>
                    </h5>
                    <h5 class="card-description" <?php if(empty($record['address'])){echo " style='display: none';"; }?>>
                        <i class="material-icons">
                            location_on
                            </i>
                          <b> Cím:</b> <?php echo $record['address']; ?>
                      </h5>
                    <h5 class="card-description">
                        <b> Leírás:</b> <?php echo $record['description']; ?>
                    </h5>
                    <div class="card-buttons">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Use either `innerHTML`, or better `textContent` of the `h4` element. Also, try pre-processing the text value by calling `trim()` on the text value.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using any buttons, it narrows the circle with every letter I write. I don't really understand how to get it to work with there things.

Comment: When did I mention buttons? Why don't you include a full example?

Comment: I added a card, that I want to search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do alot of browser interaction through puppeteer, so my example may not be a perfect fit to your situation, but I'm not entirely sure of the context.

Take a look at this example from [nitayneeman.com](https://nitayneeman.com/posts/getting-to-know-puppeteer-using-practical-examples/)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://pptr.dev');

  // Waits until the `title` meta element is rendered
  await page.waitForSelector('title');

  const title = await page.title();
  console.info(`The title is: ${title}`);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

You can await selectors (your cards) to be finished loading before searching the text.
What's happening is sometimes it's not ready and you get your bug.

For further information try checking out the [Async docs](https://javascript.info/async-await)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it would be really good to get my code to work. I'm sure it's not that hard but I just can't figure it out.